# How do I view photo thumbnails in Amazon Cloud Drive files view?

Tags: photos, cloud-storage, amazon-cloud-drive

On Amazon Cloud Drive web client, I'd like to navigate the file system structure ... then click on a folder full of photos and view those photos as large thumbnails (rather than standard file listing).

Using the Amazon Cloud Drive Photos view doesn't help, as it doesn't let me navigate via the file system structure (it will find all the folders with photos in it and let me see those with large thumbnails, nice but not what I need).

The iOS and iPad apps do this perfectly, letting me switch between large thumbnail view and standard file listing view, per folder.

Can't seem to find any option to do this on the web client.

Can anyone advise?

Ta